# vue.js: How to specify which child component to use?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, inversion-of-control

In my app there are generic and brand specific components. Let's say I have 2 brand specific components `Product_brand_A.vue` and `Product_brand_B.vue`, which I would like to display in a list. The parent component `ProductList.vue` is generic (used for both brands).

What are my options in `ProductList.vue` to specify which child component to use?

```
// ProductList.vue (generic)
import Product from 'Product.vue' // importing won't do
var ProductList = {
  components: {
    Product
  },
...
}
```

I don't want to import both child components and decide at run time, it should be a build time solution.

Comment: I don't think it can be a build-time solution, since it means that at build time your compiler already needs to know if either, or both, or none, of the brand-specific components are to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's better to use slots api here. Here's example of usage of the list component:

```
<ProductList :items="someProductsBrandA">
    <template v-slot:item="props">
        <Product_brand_A product="props.product">
        </Product_brand_B>
    </template>
</ProductList>
```

This way you can add as much different product components as you want in the future. You can check the slot API here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: I like this idea. Could you explain a bit more? How would the list template look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import both subcomponents then you would probably need to use dynamic importing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

Then you could dynamically import the subcomponent you need based on some prop that you pass to the parent (ProductList.vue).